# Best way to disassociate my name and/or delete my profile?

Tags: feature-request, support

Becuase I used google + as a sign up, now my name brings up my stack overflow user account when companies search my first name. This is really annoying since I'm job hunting.

Comment: Why are you ashamed of your SO profile being seen by job hunters? I don't see any bad posts there

Comment: Why is that a bad thing? A good idea is to just not post anything online under your real name if you'll regret it.

Comment: Well I guess he figured out how to delete his account

Comment: Reason to avoid google+ 5017

Comment: Instead of deleting your account, you could have just changed your name. (If you hit the name change limit, you can contact the staff to have them change your name manually if you have a good justification like this).

Comment: @ColeJohnson That's a wonderful ideal, but unfortunately you can't rely on everybody else always judging things fairly.